# The tag "XXX" does not exist in xml namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xaml

My SolutionName: TestBA
My AssemblyName: TestBA

Default namespace: Examples.Bootstrapper

In TestBA assemble I have Converters folder:

```
namespace Examples.Bootstrapper.Converters
{
    class PercentToPixelsConverter : IValueConverter
(...)
```

I trying to use:

```
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Examples.Bootstrapper.Converters;assembly=TestBA"
```

(...)

```
<c:PercentToPixelsConverter x:Key="MyName" />
```

I get an error:

> The tag 'PercentToPixelsConverter' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:Converters;assembly=TestBA'.

Comment: try to remove `;assembly=TestBA` if the namespace is from the same project/assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to specify assembly name if the namespace is from the same project or assembly :

```
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Examples.Bootstrapper.Converters"
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make your class `public`:

> **public** class PercentToPixelsConverter